# Beego template render partials

Tags: go, beego

Is there a functionality to render partial templates in the Beego? I used this functionality in RoR.

***Ruby on Rails partials:***
Partial templates - usually just called "partials" - are another device for breaking the rendering process into more manageable chunks. With a partial, you can move the code for rendering a particular piece of a response to its own file.

**Example from RoR:**

```
<!-- html.erb -->
<h1>New zone</h1>
<%= render partial: "form", locals: {zone: @zone} %>
```

and

```
<!-- _form.html.erb -->
<%= form_for(zone) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <b>Zone name</b><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though they are not explicitly referenced as partials in the documentation, you can compose templates like you described.
From the [documentation](http://beego.me/docs/mvc/view/view.md) for views.

```
{{template "header.html"}}
  Logic code
{{template "footer.html"}}
```

Because Beego is an MVC framework, it will automatically look for your "partials" in the views directory.

If you had another subdirectory called views/base then your partial would look like this:

```
{{template "base/header.html" .}}
```

A good reference implementation that will provide more examples in the context of a real world app, check out the [wetalk](https://github.com/beego/wetalk) project on github